# Removed the reserved header view margin for Grouped UITableView

Tags: uitableview, margin, appdelegate

By default, the grouped table view has a reserved vertical margin for every section. I don't want the header view but footer view for table view, so how to drop the margin easily?

Answer (score 0):

Override the following method of tableview's delegate to drop the header view's margin directly.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.01; // Removed the section header margin. (couldn't be 0 here, weird)
}
```